# Get a file link in PHP

Tags: php

We have a VOIP server that stores wav files for call recordings. My intention was to put together a PHP file, where i can pass the calldate and uniqueid value in the URL for the file (since the server stores these as part of the filename) to retrieve a link to the file.

However, i get the following error when trying to do so:

**"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/html/maint/helloworld.php on line 42"**

```
<?php 

function getRecordingLink($callDate, $uniqueId){

$callDate_arr = explode(' ', $callDate);

$removeChar = array('-',':');
foreach($callDate_arr as $value){
    $callDate_arr_adj[] = str_replace($removeChar,'',$value);
}

$audioDirectory_array = array();
if ($handle = opendir('/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/')) {
    while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
            $audioDirectory_array[] = $file; 
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}

foreach($audioDirectory_array as $key => $value){

    if (preg_match ("/".$uniqueId."/i", $value)) {
        if(file_exists('/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/'.$value)){
            $wavFile = $value;
            //return '<a href="/maint/modules/cdrreport/monitor/'.$wavFile.'" target="_blank">Recorded File</a>';
            return '/maint/cache/monitor/' . $wavFile;
        }
    }else{
        //return "Not Recorded";
    }

getRecordingLink ('20110513','1305274000.2'); //sample calldate and uniqueid values for testing
```

?>

Here is the description of the MySQL table from where i will be picking up values to pass to this URL for calldate and uniqueid`

```
    mysql> describe cdr
    -> ;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| calldate    | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| clid        | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| src         | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| dst         | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| dcontext    | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| channel     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| dstchannel  | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| lastapp     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| lastdata    | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| duration    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| billsec     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| disposition | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| amaflags    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| accountcode | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| uniqueid    | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| userfield   | varchar(255) | NO   |     |                     |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: What does the error message say? Just 'Internal Server Error'? Can you turn on debugging or better error messages on your server?

Comment: Just 'internal server error' - I havent tried turning on debugging, but i could look into how to do that. Im not particularly familiar with the php environment, i just borrowed this code from one of the other php files on the VOIP server since it has a gui developed in PHP

Comment: Ok. Well to be honest, you are not going to get any valuable answers either from StackOveflow or anyone (including yourself), without a good understanding of what is causing the error, or at least some more contextual information. Get hold of a better error message, edit your post to include it, and you should get a more helpful response :)

Comment: OK i'll be right back after i've switched error reporting on. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Wow looks like we both found it around the same time - damn those curly braces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, just had another good hard look at this :-p

You are missing two curly braces from the bottom of the file above `getRecordingLink()`:

```
function getRecordingLink($callDate, $uniqueId){

    $callDate_arr = explode(' ', $callDate);

    $removeChar = array('-',':');
    foreach($callDate_arr as $value){
        $callDate_arr_adj[] = str_replace($removeChar,'',$value);
    }

    $audioDirectory_array = array();
    if ($handle = opendir('/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/')) {
        while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
                $audioDirectory_array[] = $file; 
            } 
        }
        closedir($handle); 
    }

    foreach($audioDirectory_array as $key => $value){
        if (preg_match ("/".$uniqueId."/i", $value)) {
            if(file_exists('/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/'.$value)){
                $wavFile = $value;
                //return '<a href="/maint/modules/cdrreport/monitor/'.$wavFile.'" target="_blank">Recorded File</a>';
                return '/maint/cache/monitor/' . $wavFile;
            }
        }else{
            //return "Not Recorded";
        }
    }
}
getRecordingLink ('20110513','1305274000.2');
```

The error I got from [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) was:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/writecodeonline.com/php/index.php(98): eval()'d code on line 32

The file parses for me now, but I can't test what it actually does. If this doesn't work, please follow my advice in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for helping me spot the curly braces. Now i'm just get a blank screen, so i suspect the code is working in itself. I guess now i need to supply the right calldate and uniqueid for it to draw me a link right?

Comment: Yes that's right, you'll need to do `echo getRecordingLink(...)` though to output it to the page.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a genius. Thank you ever so much for your help. It's now working beautifully. I've marked your answer as accepted, if there is any other good gesture i may do for you as a thank you please do let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: PS. While i'm here, if you dont mind my asking, if i was to do echo getrecordinglink(calldate, uniqueid) and then supply that in the URL as ?calldate=xxx&uniqueid=xxx that should work too right?

Comment: It's my pleasure. Pass on a good turn to someone else and we'll call it square :-)

Comment: Of course - you would want to use `$_GET['calldate']` and `$_GET['uniqueid']` respectively. If the function is available on your server, use `mysql_escape_string(...)` on them first to ensure nobody does any weird injection on your shiney new script.